# Как вывести данные из базы данных через форму ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Вывод данных из бд через форму ajax в div с id
`<div id="result"></div>`

форма ajax:

```
<script>
  $('#form button[type=button]').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'chat.php',
    data: $('#form').serialize() + '&' + this.name + '=' + this.value,
    success: function(text) {
        console.log(data);
      }
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Слишком мало данных в вопросе и он слишком размытый. Приведите больше примеров кода и точнее задайте вопрос

Comment: ну что тут непонятного, у меня все выводится в консоль, а мне нужно в div

Comment: `$('selector').html(data);`, -- замените selector на id, class или что там у Вас.

Comment: ваш способ не помог

Comment: Вы может покажете как Вы это делаете или будем угадвывать? Если способ не помог, то значит делаете что-то не так, почитайте [документацию](https://api.jquery.com/html/) и сделайте как описано.

Comment: `<script>
$('#form button[type=button]').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'chat.php',
        data: $('#form').serialize() + '&' + this.name + '=' + this.value,
        success: function() {
            $('#result').text(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
`

Comment: А так? function(text) {`$('#result').html(text);` }

Comment: `$('result')` -- если это класс, то нужно поставить точку перед именем, вот так `$('.result')`, если id, то решетку вот так `$('#result')`.

Comment: не получается, попробовал в html() поставить - data , тоже не помогло

Comment: Наверное потому что параметр здесь `success: function(text)` именуется `text` и вместо `data`, тогда используйте `text`.

Comment: что - то начало получатся, только вывод не произошел

Answer (score 0):

В моем понимании вы хотите получить данные из бд chat.php, обработать их и уже вывести в div в html? Если я вас правильно понимаю, что бы получить данные вы должны использовать метод get, или я чего то не понимаю? пы.сы не хватает репутации для комментов не судите строго

Comment: да -да , прям в точку

Comment: если вы знаете как это сделать , это очень хорошо. Ведь у меня данные сохраняются в бд, но вот вывод никак не происходит

Comment: Если вы получаете данные корректно в консоль, внутри метода success, попробуйте внутри него же зааппендить в данные в div.